# A Simple application that can run in windows task bar

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, desktop-application

I want to write a very simple application, containing a pop-up menu when user click on it, that will appear in windows task bar, exactly like language bar, this is the only need. it does not concatin any more functionality at the time being.

Does anybody know where to start or do you have any sample code for it. I really do not know where to start since I am a Newbie!

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean Deskbands..? or A program with Icon in Notification area

Comment: I just answered this the other day. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003071/how-to-place-a-control-over-the-task-bar-in-windows-using-c/5003566#5003566) for details, including a link to sample code.

Comment: @Shekhar: The language bar is a deskband, not an icon in the notification area. So I assume that's what he is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try having a look at the [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`ITrayDeskBand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774484%28VS.85%29.aspx) but good luck with getting anything out of the MSDN documentation.

I suggest a web search for ITrayDeskBand and looking at the top hits that aren't on MSDN!

For example, this from the [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/calendar.aspx?msg=3287032) looks useful. Note that since this is a shell extension, most of the code you find will be native because .NET shell extensions are somewhat frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a [ToolBand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this.

You can either develop one yourself or use a library like [EZShellExtensions](http://www.ssware.com/ezshell/ezshell.htm).