# Taskbar Search Application

Tags: c#, .net, taskbar

I have program that is used by 4000 users to search a large database based on a large number of search scenarios.  The current application is a System Tray application and when the user clicks application icon, it opens a winform window and allows the user to enter some text and then returns the search results.  I’ve been asked by my CIO if I can just put a textbox and button in the task bars so it always there for the user.  I’ve googled everything and can’t find anything on this.  I have Window 7 and Vista OS’s some 32 bit and some 64 bit. Does anyone know of an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this CodeProject article that does something similar.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx

Also take a look at a [similar question asked here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003071/how-to-place-a-control-over-the-task-bar-in-windows-using-c-sharp).

And also [there's an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969320.aspx) posted in the question. See the references section in the article for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can register your own [Protocol Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx#app_ex). Then you can add the address toolbar to the taskbar. Then a user can just type "search:steak".