# How to create this kind of GUI on windows

Tags: win32gui

There is a win7 application which can show a progress bar on the win7 task bar.

I was wondering how is it implemented. Is there any Win32 API can do this?

[image]

Comment: Seems [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003071/how-to-place-a-control-over-the-task-bar-in-windows-using-c-sharp) is what i am looking for.

Comment: That is indeed a [DeskBand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099.aspx), however do note that the [DeskBand Shell interfaces are deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj635743.aspx) as of Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You should inhert `CProgressCtrl` class and redraw the control.
Handle `WM_PAINT` message as painting the control in `OnPaint` function.